# AngularJS - Redirect old url to new url after changing hashbang mode to html5 mode

Tags: angularjs, redirect, routes, hashbang

I want to change the routing mode of my app from hashbang (`#/path`) to html5 mode (`/path`).

How can I redirect the old URLs to the new ones?
The situation is we already sent out some emails with the old URLs. People are still able to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Angular does it automatically. (v1.4.10)